# mysql start ubuntu - ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I cant start `mysql` server on local machine.

Run mysql start, display error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

How solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try entering

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

it will ask you to put in your password then

it looks like your MySql is running

and if that doesnt work do

```
mysql start -uroot -p
```

alternatively look at this https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/start-stop-mysql-from-the-command-line-terminal-osx-linux/

Comment: yes, i  input myt password and enter. - "Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  
Your MySQL connection id is 44."  why i cant run mysql server?

Comment: Your MySql is running if you can login. can you show what you get after inputting the password and may i ask why would you say it doesn't work. By the way Russian is ok if you are having issues translating.

Comment: username@username-Lenovo-B590:~$ mysql -u root -p 
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 44
Server version: 5.7.12-0ubuntu1.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> ^C

Comment: Yes that means its running if you type `show databases;` it will show your server is working type exit to get out of mysql